# showing comments for specific users custom profile page

Tags: wordpress, comments

I am looking for a way to list the most recent comments from a specific post on a different page of my sites front end.

I have a page with a 'reviews about me' tab, a 'reviews i've left', tab and a 'recent reviews'. The last two are done... but the first one I've been struggling with. The site uses a custom post type for the profile screen where the reviews are being left and the 'website' field in the default wp profile to determine which post is the logged in users profile.

I have studied the info about wp_list_comments found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments  at length and can not seem to figure it out.

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: P.S. I also have studied the get_comments reference https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments and have not been able to figure this one out.

Comment: I think the way to go is using the [WP_Comment_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query) class to create a custom query.

Comment: I will look into that. However, from skimming over the reference docs for it it looks like it use the same array options as the other two and thus I will have the same problems. I am trying to turn the query into a short code.

Comment: I am still very lost on this. I added further description of the issue to the original post. Any help would be appreciated.